# Iptables doesn't allow network traffic from open ports

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I changed the policy of the INPUT chain, adding the following command.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

After I inserted the next rules in order to allow input packets from the network ports 80 and 443 but the ports are still closed (e.g. I can't use web browser).

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Output from `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How could I allow network traffic from HTTP and HTTPS ports?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, the rules don't work.

Comment: Questions usually end with `?`

Comment: well, first off, are you sure you have a service listening on those ports? `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep -E '80|443'`

Comment: Yes services http and https listen to the ports 80 and 443 respectively.

Comment: I’m confused: Are these rules for the PC where you want to open your browser and surf the web?

Comment: Is there some reason you are expecting to receive packets with a destination port of 80 or 443? Is there a web server on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would appear (to me) that while the traffic is allowed out your network, its not being allowed back.  There is normally a rule to allow inbound traffic associated with the outbound traffic which is missing.  Try adding the following line to fix your issue -

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Depending on the way your network works, its also possible that the failure is happening because you are not allowing DNS to be resolved, (you should allow UDP and TCP to your nameservers on port 53 for this).

Also (and this is a bit contentious/controvertial), I suggest allowing ICMP through your network -

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

This can make debugging things a lot easier, and also not allowing some kinds of ICMP can break traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You ave a mistake in your rules.
Your rule says INPUT (so what enter to the computer or server) with destination port. It means that a client try to connect to a website hosted in your computer/server. However, you said you can't connect to a web server, the the rules are wrong.

It should be sport instead of dport

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
```